# Create dynamic parameters for Models in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: ajax, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm new to Sencha Touch (and MVC mostly for that matter), we have a UI team member using the Sencha Designer 2 to create the interface, but at the moment he's create a lot of different models (one model for each store). But there is only the one AJAX file that it is referencing, just with different parameters.

So is it possible to make the parameters dynamic depending on which store is trying to access it.
Ie, if store User is trying to access the model can it put in "ajax.php?store=user", if store Facebook is trying to access the model it can put in "ajax.php?store=facebook", so on and so forth. It just seems silly to me to have one model per store, very redundant.

If this is an obvious fix, i am sorry, like i said im new to Sench Touch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a empty Model for all of your stores

```
Ext.define( 'SomeNamespace.model.SomeModel', { extend : 'Ext.data.Model' } );
```

and provide [extraParams](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax) in your store

```
Ext.define ('SomeNamespace.store.someStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'SomeNamespace.model.SomeModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/ajax.php',
        extraParams : {
           store : 'someStore'
        }
    }
});
```